# Date comparison in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I created this method to compare dates: whether date < 1 week, date < 1 year, or date > 1 year. This is the method:

```
if self.created_at > Date.today + 7 && self.created_at < Date.today + 365
  return 'old'
elsif self.created_at > Date.today - 7
  return 'new'
elsif self.created_at < Date.today + 365
  return 'very_old'
end
```

< 1 year does not work.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat cleaner version

```
days_ago = Date.today - created_at.to_date

return if days_ago > 365
         'very old'
       elsif days_ago > 7
         'old'
       else
         'new'
       end
```